# Product reference field causes $title to be empty

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce

**Update: After removing fields one by one, I've discovered that the Product reference field caused `$title` to be empty.**

I have several content types which are displaying both the `<title>` and `$title` well, but in my "Product Display" content type (of commerce kickstart) I find that the `$title`  header is missing, although the `<title>` tag is there, i.e. the title bar of my browser is displaying the page title correctly. The contents of `<title>` and `$title` are similar. Excep that `<title>` has the site name added to the end of the node title.

I've viewed page source it shows that h1 isn't printed. I've never written any code to hide any h1 tags. I'm using Display suite on that page and I've disabled it on that content type and it didn't help. I am not using Context on that page. Please advise me on how I should proceed, thanks!

Update: Devel->load shows that the title is set correctly, but when I created a template for that node (page--node--42.tpl.php), and tested if it worked by hiding the header and footer, I added this line of code

```
<h1 class="page--title title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
```

but all I got is am empty `$title`

Update 2: I've inserted a block using  [current-page:title] and it works, however I'd prefer not to stick with this duct-tape solution if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 to 6 hours of searching for the answer with Emko, we found that commenting out line 67 to 76 of this module fixed the problem.

```
profiles\commerce_kickstart\modules\commerce_kickstart\commerce_kickstart_product_ui
\commerce_kickstart_product_ui.module


/**
* Override or insert variables into the page template.
*/
function commerce_kickstart_product_ui_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
$product_display_types = commerce_product_reference_node_types();
if (isset($vars['node']->type) && isset($product_display_types[$vars['node']->type])) {
$vars['title'] = "";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the content types display tab. It may be set to hide the title.

Comment: Thanks, I have title being displayed in the content field correctly, but I can't get it to display in the header

Comment: That'll need to be modified inside the page.tpl.php template in your theme. Copy or move the $title variable wherever you want it to display.

Comment: thanks, I checked to see that my other content types are displaying the title correctly in the header. Just for the sake of testing I added <?php print render($title); ?> and it worked for all the pages but the "product display" content type

Comment: The product display content type most likely has it's own .tpl.php page that overrides the default page.tpl.php template. That explains why it works on all other pages but the product display. Another possibility is that the product display is generated by a view using the views module. If we could connect via chat or google it would be easier for us to debug this thing. Look around at the above and see if you can spot anything.

Comment: Thanks again :) It shouldn't be a template problem since I tried targeting the node with page--node--42.tpl.php and printing $title give me nothing (I did test to make sure the template works by not printing the header). I'm using Display Suite (not views to generate the page) for the Product Display content type but I tested it by turning it off. Of course we could chat, how do you propose we do it? there's not private messaging system that I know of. Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: do you have an account on drupal.org? I could send you a pm there

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/user/1248540

Answer (score 0):

Product Reference module pulls fields from the product entity to your product display (node), this naming has been simplified in Commerce Kicsktart and you can find the product displays as simply products and your products as product variations, more on this here: [product vs product type vs product display in drupal commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17542/product-vs-product-type-vs-product-display-in-drupal-commerce)

So in your kickstart installation, the product title is coming from the product entity, if you go to `admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types` you'll see all your product types and then you can configure your field for each view mode to control the title display.

Hope this is what's troubling you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I read you wrongly but I think you might have misunderstood my problem. I can display title_field and <title>, but my `$title` is null. The title fields for both product display and variation aren't empty. I've tried hiding and displaying them but it doesn't solve the problem :(